# Sending attachment in Word format does not work in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, google-data-api

I've been able to send attachment in PDF format successfully but when I try to send attachment in Word format, I get this error:

"Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 404. Truncated server response:

I've tried several ways suggested in this site but I just couldn't make it work.

Will very much appreciate any help on this topic. I'm a newbie in Google Script.

Here's my code:

```
//=================================================
//  Email Employment Letter as Word format, not PDF
//=================================================

function EmailCertAsWordDoc(requestor, name, newCopyID) {
  var email = requestor; 
  var id = DocumentApp.openById(newCopyID);
  var subject = "Auto-generated Employment Letter"; 
  var body = "\n\nAttached is the Employment Letter that you created for " + name + ". \n\n\n\n\n ";

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + id + "&format=docx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docx = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();

  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, {
      Body: body,
      attachments:[docx]     
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. To obtain the export url, you need to use the **file id**, no the file itself - in your case it is `newCopyID`
2. Sending word files as attachments is unfortunately a little bit more complicated than pdfs. To make it work, you can create a word file on your drive, and then send it as an URL within your email body.

Sample:

```
function EmailCertAsWordDoc(requestor, name, newCopyID) {
  var email = requestor; 
  var fileName = DocumentApp.openById(newCopyID).getName();
  var subject = "Auto-generated Employment Letter"; 
  var body = "\n\nAttached is the Employment Letter that you created for " + name + ". \n\n\n\n\n ";

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + newCopyID + "&format=docx&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docx = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var file=DriveApp.createFile(docx).setName(fileName).getUrl();
  body+=" "+file;
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final working code after following ziganotschka's advice:

```
//=================================================
//  Email Employment Letter as Word format, not PDF
//=================================================

function EmailCertAsWordDoc(email, name, newCopyID) {

  var subject = "Auto-generated Employment Letter"; 
  var body = "\n\nAttached is the Employment Letter that you created for " + name + ". \n\n\n\n\n ";  
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + newCopyID + '&exportFormat=docx';
  var options = {
      headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
      }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var doc = response.getBlob();

  //Create the docx file in my TEMP folder in Google Drive and send
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName('Employment Letter - '+ name + '.docx');
  DriveApp.getFolderById('<ID of my TEMP folder in Google Drive>').addFile(file);   
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());

  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      Body: body,
      attachments:[blob]     
    });  

  //Remove the docx file from the TEMP folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```